# What is running behind when creating Django project with one line command

Tags: python, django

a fresh question about Django. It maybe silly...I wonder what is running behind the scene when I create a Django project with one line command. Well, I have done with couples of Django projects, the framework is really powerful. So this question is just jumping into my mind. who created the directory structure. Is it a script in some installed Django folder? where can I find it?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean django.core.management.commands.startproject?

Comment: what I mean is the command line  "Django-admin startproject XXX" is always used to create Django project with a directory structure, like create-react-app. So I wonder if the command activates a script to do so. and where is the script, can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

It is in /lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands.
And by creating child Class from BaseCommand class can create customised Command.